# How to fix multiple bounding boxes being drawn around same object in image?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, object-detection

I have been training my model for foot detection. It has two classes, **"left_foot"** and **"right_foot"**. After getting some acceptable loss value, I decided to give it a test. But it detects many instances of the same object in the same area. Take a look at the following image:

[image]

I'm using **ssdlite_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_05_09** for transfer learning, downloaded from [this repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md) as I'm gonna be using this detection for an android application.

What could be causing this? How can I fix this? Will simply continuing training fix this issue or will it just make it worse?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but changing some configurations in [this file](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs/ssdlite_mobilenet_v2_coco.config) might help.

For example, you could increase the value of **IoU** in [this line](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/444e8c799d7defa93ecd15b9136d7351911920eb/research/object_detection/samples/configs/ssdlite_mobilenet_v2_coco.config#L133). Also, increasing the [minimum scale of anchors](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/444e8c799d7defa93ecd15b9136d7351911920eb/research/object_detection/samples/configs/ssdlite_mobilenet_v2_coco.config#L34) might have some impact, since the size of your objects seem to be quite large.

Comment: Thank you so much! Changing the IoU threshold did the trick. Although, upon increasing the threshold it made even more boxes, bringing it down did the job. I don't exactly understand the math behind the IoU I'll look into it. Thanks though!